# Can we use the word "steady" to describe a person?

Tags: adjectives, personality

I know it's possible to say *steady arms* or *steady decision*.

But what about people? I found in the student's book that this word is allowed to use when you describe personalities.

**Is it true? And what does mean "steady person"?**

Comment: Michael, is it similar to "calm person", "a person who lives in harmony" in this case?

Comment: Not always. A person living in harmony may not be steady in their own pursuits to avoid friction with others. Steady people aren't confrontational, but they are also fairly resolute in their path in life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [free dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/steady), it is fairly clear which aspects may relate to a person's character.

stead·y  (stĕd′ē)

adj. stead·i·er, stead·i·est

1. Firm in position or place; fixed.
2. **Direct and unfaltering; sure.**
3. Free or almost free from change, variation, or fluctuation; uniform: a steady increase in value; a steady breeze.
4. **Not easily excited or upset**: steady nerves.
5. **Unwavering, as in purpose**; steadfast.
6. **Reliable; dependable.**
7. **Temperate; sober**.

tr. & intr.v. stead·ied, stead·y·ing, stead·ies

To make or become steady.

interj. Nautical

Used to direct a helmsman to keep a ship's head in the same direction: Steady as she goes!

Answer (score 2):

A person who is steady is balanced, reliable and doesn't cause difficulties. "He was a steady employee, always coming in on time, finishing his project on deadline, with a friendly pleasant manner."

Steady can also mean a person that one is seeing exclusively, as in a steady boyfriend or girlfriend. "I'm not interested in dating your sister because I have a steady girlfriend."